# Is there any way configure Application Gateway for Least Connection?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I use Azure Application Gateway. When I review the documents, I only see `round-robin distribution of incoming traffic, cookie-based session affinity, URL path-based routing` for Application Load Balancer. Is there any way to use `Least Connection` for that. This is available on AWS, but I couldn't see it on Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via https://resources.azure.com/
You should open that resource; find your RG and APP GW and you will see setting
routingmethod -> roundrobin and you can change it to leastresponsetime

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works#how-an-application-gateway-routes-a-request
Round-robin (or cookie based affinity) is all you can do.  Kinda lame.

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation does not mention any other kind of distributing algorithm. But when define AG, you can see there's other 2 options to pick, including **LeastConnections** and **IpHash**. Hope it helps!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/applicationgateways?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#applicationgatewayloaddistributionpolicypropertiesfo